# Get original data array from probability density values and bins of numpy histogram

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, histogram, reverse

My purpose is to calculate the original data array from the infromation of probability density and bins of np.histogram function.

For example:

```
import random
a = random.sample(xrange(100), 50)
n, bin = np.histogram(a,bins=100,range=(-10,10), normed=True)
```

I would like to get a from n and bin. I used np.digitize, but it doesn;t seem to be proper solution.

Actually my orginal purpose is to calculate skewness and kurtosis of original dat from this histogram. So, I have tried to convert n and bin to original data. If I can get skewness and kurtosis from the histogram directly, it would be perfect.

Thanks to user3823992, I tried scipy.stats.rv_discrete function to get skewness and kurtosis from bins and probability density function.
My edited code is:

```
a = random.sample(xrange(100), 50)
n, bin = np.histogram(a,bins=100,range=(-10,10), normed=True)
b2=bin[:-1]
print np.mean(a), np.var(a), sp.skew(a),sp.kurtosis(a)
dist = sp.rv_discrete(values=(b2,n))
print dist.stats(moments='mvsk')
```

However, the results from np.mean(a), np.var(a), sp.skew(a),sp.kurtosis(a) and dist.stats(moments='mvsk') are too much different. According to document for scipy.stats.rv_discrete, one of two tuples in 'values' should be the points with integers (in this case, b2) and sum of the other (in this case, n) should be 1.
The problem is the numbers in my b2 are not integers and the sum of 'n' is not also 1.
I multiplied the bin width to n and tried again. However, still didn't work.

Any idea or help would be appreciated.
Best regards,

Hoonill

Comment: Rather than opening a new question, please **edit and improve this one**. Consider reading the material available in [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.stats.rv_discrete` has you covered. It'll help you make a random distribution class from your data. The result will have a whole slew of handy methods.  The `.stats` method will give you the first four moments.  If you don't specify, it'll just return mean (`m`) and variance (`v`).

```
b2=bin[:-1]
print mean(a), var(a), scipy.stats.skew(a)
dist = scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(b2,n))
print dist.stats(moments='mvsk')
```

The above should be compatible with your code.  Just reorganize to make use of the output.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I checked the document for scipy.stats.rv_discrete(). According to that document, for two tuples in values((xk, pk), xk should be integers and sum of pk should be 1, but my b2 and n are not like that. I am not sure whether that was problem, but anyway mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis from original data didn't match with value from dist.stats. Do you have any idea fro this? Thank you, Isaac